# WPF binding And DataContext

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have a situation where my view has a DataContext bound to the ViewModel but one of my controls inside the view has its DataContext Set to a property of the ViewModel.  The first time I change that ViewModel, it shows the changes but after that, if I change property inside the ViewModel no changes are reflected back to the view.

```
//Somewhere inside my View
            <TaicoControl:FlashMessage DataContext="{Binding FlashMessage}"
                                   DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                   FadesOutAutomatically="True"
                                   FontFamily="BPG Arial"
                                   Message="{Binding Message}"
                                   MessageType="{Binding FlashType}" />
//End of the View




public sealed class ShellViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public FlashMessageModel FlashMessage { get; private set; }

    protected override void SetupEvents()
    {
        RegisterForEvent<SystemBaloonRequiered>(OnBaloonRequest);
        RegisterForEvent<FlashRequest>(OnFlashRequested);
        base.SetupEvents();
    }

    #region Message Handlers


    private void OnFlashRequested(FlashRequest obj)
    {
        FlashMessage = null;
        FlashMessage = new FlashMessageModel { Message = obj.Message, FlashType = obj.FlashType };
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => FlashMessage);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Can you paste the binding expression and the view model property being utilized?

Comment: Make sure the Mode of the binding is not OneTime and the ViewModel and the property implement INotifyPropertyChanged correctly. Post your code to get feedback

Comment: Double checked it is set up correctly I even posted code here

Comment: Are you sure it isn't updating the DataContext? Use a tool like Snoop WPF Spy to spy on what the DataContext of the user control is. I'll bet that it is actually the new object and the error lies within that control. Also, ensure that you are calling your OnFlashRequested using breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

This is the classic case of not implementing *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface.

When you change the value of *FlashMessage* there is no way for the UI to know that. So, to let the UI know, you raise *PropertyChanged* event with the property name ("FlashMessage" in your case).

Once you implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface and notify property change for *FlashMessage* it should workout just fine.

### Example:

```
public sealed class ShellViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var temp = PropertyChanged;

        if(temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public FlashMessageModel _flashMessage;

    public FlashMessageModel FlashMessage 
    { 
        get { return _flashMessage; } 
        private set 
        { 
            _flashMessage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlashMessage");
        }
    } 
}
```

-EDIT-

Try changing your code from following:

```
FlashMessage = null;   
FlashMessage = new FlashMessageModel { Message = obj.Message, FlashType = obj.FlashType };   
RaisePropertyChanged(() => FlashMessage);
```

to following:

```
FlashMessage.Message = obj.Message;
FlashMessage.FlashType = obj.FlashType;
```

Comment: Where Did u see INotifyPropertyChanged not being implemented? Viewmodelbase already implements that so there is no need to implement this in concrete viewmodel. please ask before making notes

Comment: In general, ViewModelBase should be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. Otherwise this is the correct approach.

Comment: Id Does implement and I use that Base type on every ViewModel classes and there are no problems

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/New-control-to-get-rid-of-377ffb5a  this is the control I am trying to use and after it closes I am not able to show it again using above code

Comment: Have you implemented property notifications for *Message* and *FlashType*? If yes, what if you don't create a new object of FlashMessageModel and just assign new values to *Message* and *FlashType* properties? I think there is a bug that when *DataContext* is set to null once, it stops updating the bindings.

Comment: U mean to directly expose message and type properties from ShellViewModel?

Comment: Updated answer text with what I mean.

Comment: Nop tried that as well but there is only one update so after showing that message first time no more messages are shown

Comment: @decyclone: Setting the DataContext vs. updating the value that is being bound to null are two different things. If you update the DataContext at all you are resetting the bindings. If you, instead, update the bound value to null that is all you have done... the bindings remain in tact.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on that binding, it should be hit. Or try using a "Debug Converter" to see if that binding is updated or not. If the breakpoint is not hit on binding or in debug converter, you have made a mistake somewhere setting up the binding.